# obtaining different behaviours testing web pages on android emulator and real device

Tags: android, virtualbox

I am developing a web site that is to be seen on a samsung galaxy notes. im  using asp.net and iscroll mainly.

I do not own a galaxy notes, but a partner im working with at distance have one, and he describes me the results on the galaxy notes.

I installed android 2.3 on my virtualbox,  which is supposed to be the same version as the galaxy notes my partner is using, so i can see the results myself, the weird stuff is that i see different display results from the published website that the ones that my partner sees in the real galaxy notes device. being more specific, my partner has certain visual glitches which i dont, which means i cant work on resolving the offending glitches in my presence.

is this a drawback to be expected from testing on a virtual device, or i missing something?

Comment: Are you emulating the screen size correctly?

Comment: honestly no.is that a major factor and  could it be the only reason i do not see the visual glitches that my partener experiments?

Comment: That would depend on the nature of the glitches, but possibly.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick search around the web tells me that the Galaxy Note has a slightly different browser than the stock Android browser.

This means that Samsung must have touched it and that (while likely comparable) this should be considered a different browser. You are not guaranteed to see the same results.

Comparing screenshots I see that the browsers on the Galaxy Note and the Galaxy Tab (the older one) probably are from the same stable so you could try to reproduce the glitch using the optional Galaxy Tab package in the Android 2.2 SDK.